# Language independent way to find all the users with admin access to a computer via powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a powershell script that can find all users, domain and local, that have admin access to the current computer. The script works fine, until you change the language of the computer. I would like to know if there are other ways to go about this. Below is my current script

```
$strComputer = "."
    $computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $strComputer + ",computer")
    $Group = $computer.psbase.children.find("Administrators")
    $Props = $Group.psbase.invoke("Members")  | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Adspath", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
```

If you doa Write-Host $Props you can get an output of all the users formatted as {DOMAIN}/{USERNAME}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use 'well-known SIDs' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/well-known-sids

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [well-known SID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) of the group to find it. There is some discussion in a [blog post here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/11/02/how-can-i-determine-the-name-of-the-local-administrators-group/), but that uses VBScript and WMI (`winmgmts:\\`).

If you want to use `WinNT://` like you already are, then this will search through the local groups for the group with the SID `S-1-5-32-544`, which corresponds to the `Administrators` group.

```
$strComputer = "."
$computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $strComputer + ",computer")

$Group = $computer.Children |
    Where {
        (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.objectSid.Value,0).ToString()
            -eq "S-1-5-32-544"
    } | Select -First 1
```

That `New-Object` bit is because the `objectSid` property is presented as a byte array, so you need to create a `SecurityPrincipal` object with it to be able to convert it to a string to do the comparison.